# Get-AzTrafficManagerProfile command is not running from inside the pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

I need to update the traffic manager profile in the pipeline to switch resources, when I run the command Get-AzTrafficManagerProfile in my local az cli with me logged-in it runs with no issues,
but when I ran it as a task part of the Azure pipeline it threw the bellow error:

Get-AzTrafficManagerProfile : No account found in the context. Please login using Connect-AzAccount.

also tried to call Connect-AzAccount from inside the pipeline and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the command `Get-AzTrafficManagerProfile` successfully in devops, you need to use the [`Azure PowerShell task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) and authenticated with the [`Azure Resource Manager service connection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-azure-resource-manager).

Please refer to the steps below.

1.Create an `Azure PowerShell task`, in `Azure subscription` -> `Available Azure subscriptions` -> select the subscription you want to run `Get-AzTrafficManagerProfile` against.

[image]

2.Then click the `Authorize` button, it will create an `Azure Resource Manager service connection` automatically for you and assign a [Contributor RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) at the subscription scope.

**Note:** Make sure your user account logged in devops is the `Owner/User Access administrator` in the subscription, otherwise you have no permission to do this successfully.

[image]

3.Then in the `Inline Script`, just use `Get-AzTrafficManagerProfile` directly, no need to login manually, because it will login with the service connection automatically.

[image]

4.Test the task, it works fine.

[image]